# Backbone and changing model attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am developing an application partly based on Backbone.js [todo example app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html). Everything was working nicely, until I tried adding editing feature. What I found is some strange behaviour.

I have is some kind of form, which creates new model object and adds it to collection. When new model is created (binded to 'add' event), also new view is created and added to dom. Just like in that todo app and it works.

Well now I try to add edit feature. I create input elements in view object method and try to "submit" changes. I try to do this first by simply changing model attributes with view.model.set -method. This works, but some weird event is triggered. This could be fine, since I would like to render view again as model is changed.

The main problem: In my view (working one) object there is render method containing this debug line: 'console.log(this)'. When view object is created first time by form, this line outputs right object. When I try to edit model and set new value to it, debug prints totally different object. This doesnt work and rendering fails.

I hope that these examples are enough.

Main view:

```
this.myCollection.bind('add', function(model){
    var myView= new myViewRow({
        model: model
    });         
    $("#container").find('tbody').append(myView.render().el);
}, this);
```

and in myView:

```
render: function() {
    console.log(this);

    var data = this.getAsArray();
    $(this.el).html(content);
    return this;
}
```

Any tips what I am doing wrong? What event set method triggers and why my render method is after that in wrong object?

Comment: Could you post the complete views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the initialize method of your Backbone view:

```
_.bindAll(this, "render");
```

See the [Backbone.js FAQ](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this) for an explanation of this. It's a common practice in Backbone views to make sure that the `this` variable points to the View object defined in the current function scope, as one would normally want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to listen fot the change event, you have to bind the listener function to the current view http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this

Comment: This is good point and probably and has something to do with my problem. Anyways I have this line in my view initialize method: this.model.bind('change', this.render, this)